# How to output taxonomy term (incl. link to archive) on author.php?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, user-meta

I have used the excellent tutorial of Justin Tadlock on [Custom user taxonomies in WordPress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) to add a Blog custom taxonomy to both my Posts post_type as well as the user object_type.

In his tutorial Justin then outputs a list of users that share the same (profession) taxonomy.

I on the other hand would like to output the specific term of my Blog taxonomy on the `author.php` archive, together with some other user_meta-fields I already have added to the User Profile.

How would I be able to accomplish this? Ideally it not only outputs the taxonomy term, but also a link to the term archive.

Comment: You want to output categories, for example, assigned to posts that your author has written?

Comment: @s_ha_dum  
I have a custom taxonomy called "Blog" which is attached to the Post post_type and the User object_type according to the tutorial linked above. When on the `author.php` it usually shows the profile of the author and then lists the Posts written by that author, correct? Now in that profile I want to output the associated Blog (incl. link). I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms#Examples).

In my use case scenario:

```
$blog_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'blog' );
if ( ! empty( $blog_terms ) ) {
  if ( ! is_wp_error( $blog_terms ) ) {
    foreach( $blog_terms as $term ) {
      echo '<p>' . __( 'Associated Blog: ', 'wys' ) . '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'blog' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>'; 
    }
  }
}
```